# Python Newbie Questions - Not printing the right values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm completely new to coding so please be patient. What am i doing wrong. Despite following the instructions given python wont allow the code to bring the expected output. This is the course i'm doing

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRY_xjL35v0&t=428s](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

stamp 9:31

I'm doing a course on python at the moment and i was told if i type this:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
print('Blastoff!')
```

the output would be this:

```
5
4
3
2
1
Blastoff!
```

instead i get a SyntaxError because python would allow `print('Blastoff!')` to be aligned with `while n > 0:`. When i try an alternative way i get:

```
n=5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
    print('Blastoff!')
```

and output:

```
5
Blastoff!
4
Blastoff!
3
Blastoff!
2
Blastoff!
1
Blastoff!
```

When i tried the below i got SyntaxError:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
print('Blastoff')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's the full error? The code you show looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not formatted correctly. Regardless, I think your issue is indentation (even though everything is on one line in your question, please format your code correctly).

In python, blocks of code are grouped together based on their indentation. What i'm guessing you have is:

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
    print('Blastoff!')
```

But what you want to have is

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
print('Blastoff!')
```

so that it outputs "Blastoff!" once after the loop, and not in every iteration inside the loop.

Comment: Got SyntaxError                                                                                                                     
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
print('Blastoff')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax